# Will a 4.5V - 0 - 4.5V transformer work with a 9V battery?

Tags: transformer, ac, dc

I am concerned as to whether my circuit will work or not before I build it (I am concerned about the battery voltage.)

[image]

This is what I have but my transformer is 4.5V - 0 - 4.5V. Is there any way I can change this to work with a 4.5V - 0 - 4.5V transformer?

Also it looks wrong to have the positive side of the battery go into the 0v part of the transformer but it is probably correct.

Comment: Which voltage are you wanting to create?  120v or 220v (as in the transformer specs in the schematic)?

Comment: I'm very confused by this circuit. A transformers with two positive ends? Connecting the battery 9V to  the (presumably) 0V center? I must be interpreting this the wrong way because that would create an 18V short across each transistor. What's this called and where can I read more about it?

Comment: Oh I see, the high voltage here is not the input but the output... Makes more sense now. I guess the specific resistor values and transistor properties will somehow cause it to oscillate at 50/60 Hz?

Comment: If it is a 50 or 60 Hz transformer, what should set the frequency of this circuit to this frequency? There are two capacitors of the proper size missing.

Comment: Ahh. Yet another circuit from one of the shameless alternative reality factories. No, this circuit will not work as shown, because the wizards who posted it never bothered to build the thing, and they certainly don’t understand what makes it work or not. **You’re following advice from people who can’t even tell if a simple multivibrator will work.** And who surely know they have no clue, yet they post and mislead anyway. We should start banning links to those sites. They don’t deserve any revenue. Useless.

Comment: transformers do not have a `0v part`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need the circuit of an astable multivibrator. There are two RC combinations determining high and low period time.

t1 = R1 * C1 * ln(2) ; t2 = R2 * C2 * ln(2) ; t1 = t2 = 10 ms for 50 Hz oscillation. The calculation of C1 and C2 is left as an exercise.

For a 9 V battery, a transformer with a split secondary winding with 18 V should be used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbjGq6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can I use 2 10k resistors in parallel? Also, how can I calculate capacitor I am very new.

Comment: @NoahBurchell You got all the equations neccesary to calculate the capacitors. ln(2) means the natural logarithm of 2, the value is 0.6931

Comment: using maths I got 2.88 is that F, mF, μF, or nF?

Comment: If you use 0.01 for 10 ms and 5000 for 5 kOhm, you get a result telling you what it is  F, mF, μF, or nF ; 2.88 is right by the but the order of magnitude is missing

Comment: Sorry this is so late but i finally got around to getting the materials to build this circuit. Anyway, I built it and it isnt working and when I simulated it again (with artificial imbalance) it didnt work correctly. (I used two 10k resistors in parallel for both the 10k because the store didnt sell 5k and three 1uF capacitors in parallel because they didnt have 2.88uF (I did the calculation and it came out to 0.0108........ so i thought it would be close enough) do you know why this may be? if it would be easier to make with 555 timer i have one of those also so... yeah.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Isnt 5000*0.00000288*ln(2) = 0.01 or am i just stupid

Comment: nvm the simulator works i think its a problem with my solderiong

Comment: @NoahBurchell 5E3 * 2.88E-6 * ln(2) is 9.981E-3 tells me my hp 32S RPN

Answer (score 2):

> Will a 4.5v - 0 - 4.5v transformer work with a 9v battery?

Yes, but with the following changes:

1. Battery - 4.5 V instead of 9 V.
2. Resistors R1 and R2 - 5 kΩ instead of 10 kΩ.

The battery polarity shown is correct.

Comment: No it will not work because the frequency of oscillation will be much too high for a 50 or 60 Hz transformer.

Comment: @Uwe - Hi, It'll work for the purpose for which it was intended.  https://www.eleccircuit.com/high-volt-shock-by-transistor-2sc458/

Answer (score 1):

For your information, one picture for the original schematic. (Possibly Vce max breakdown).

[image]

Here is what happens with some "add" in the original circuit ...
The capacitors added help for a sinusoidal output ...
NB: this is dependent on the load because no regulation & feedback is used.
The oscillating frequency is not 50 or 60 Hz.

[image]

Comment: The OP's circuit isn't for a sine-wave 50 / 60 Hz inverter. https://www.eleccircuit.com/high-volt-shock-by-transistor-2sc458/

Comment: Yes. Ok, I tested the original schematic. It makes high voltage pulses, what is the goal. Voltages between collector-emitter are also very high, and somewhat greater than Vce max, so Q1 & Q2 will not work "very long" ... There are other means of doing some "well" known high voltage pulses.

Comment: Hi Antonio, Thank you very much for the information.